# get mysql query to work with class with namespaces

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm creating a XML file for SEPA Direct Debit.

I'm using https://github.com/dmitrirussu/php-sepa-xml-generator and have the example work ok BUT I don't seem to be able to use it INSIDE A MYSQL WHILE...

I have used composer to install throught composer.json.

EXAMPLE WORKING:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//When you start to generate a SEPA Xml File, need to choose PAIN
$directDebitTransaction = \SEPA\XMLGenerator::PAIN_008_001_02;// For Direct Debit transactions is By Defaut

$sepa = SEPA\Factory\XMLGeneratorFactory::createXmlGeneratorObject($directDebitTransaction)->addXmlMessage(
    SEPA\Factory\XMLGeneratorFactory::createXMLMessage()
        ->setMessageGroupHeader(
        SEPA\Factory\XMLGeneratorFactory::createXMLGroupHeader()
            ->setMessageIdentification(1)
            ->setInitiatingPartyName('Amazing SRL ???? ыаывпавпва '))
            ->addMessagePaymentInfo(
        SEPA\Factory\XMLGeneratorFactory::createXMLPaymentInfo()
            ->setPaymentInformationIdentification(6222)
            ->setSequenceType('RCUR')
            ->setCreditorAccountIBAN('MD24 AG00 0225 1000 1310 4168')
            ->setCreditorAccountBIC('AABAFI42')
            ->setCreditorName('Amazing SRL')
            ->setCreditorSchemeIdentification('FR07ZZZ519993')
            ->setRequestedCollectionDate('2013-08-06')
            ->setAggregatePerMandate(true) //Default Transaction aggregation option = true
/* TRANSACCION - 1 */
            ->addDirectDebitTransaction( //First transaction
            SEPA\Factory\XmlGeneratorFactory::createXMLDirectDebitTransaction()
                ->setInstructionIdentification(3)
                ->setEndToEndIdentification(3)
                ->setInstructedAmount(100.5)
                ->setDebtorName('Roy SRL')
                ->setDebitIBAN('FR14 2004 1010 0505 0001 3M02 606')
                ->setDebitBIC('AABAFI22') //Optional
                ->setMandateIdentification('SDD000000016PFX0713') //unique Identifier
                ->setDateOfSignature('2013-08-03')
                ->setCurrency('EUR')
                ->setDirectDebitInvoice(122)
           )
/* TRANSACCION - 2 */
// ...
/* TRANSACCION - 3 */
// ...
/* TRANSACCION - N */
// ...
    )
);

/* this is the part I need to use to REPLACE the transactions parts above */
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM test"))
{
    while ($data = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        /*
        * here we get the data needed for the addDirectDebitTransaction()
        */
    }
}
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();

/* save XML */
$sepa->view()->save(realpath(__DIR__) .'/test.xml');

/* EOF */
```

As I said, this works but I dont undertand well the namespaces and I'm not able to do such a simple thing...

Help, please...

Answer (score 0):

You don't work with XML, but SEPA. XML is only used indirectly as a serialization format.

You call the methods of that specific PHP library that generates the SEPA message.

That said, generate the payment information first and store it into a variable. Use the loop to add transactions, generate the message and append the payment information.

Comment: that is what i want but How to CALL to add the transactions? That is what i dont know from the code above.

Comment: I have the contents saved in var $sepa, but INSIDE de while loop... how do I ADD the data?

I want to know how to do this:

    $sepa->[WHAT HERE?]->addDirectDebitTransaction($object_generated_from_inside_the_query)

Comment: `SEPA\Factory\XMLGeneratorFactory::createXMLPaymentInfo()` creates the payment information. This is used as an argument for `->addMessagePaymentInfo()` of the sepa message created by `SEPA\Factory\XMLGeneratorFactory::createXMLMessage()`. Split the nested function call!

Comment: Split the nested function call! .... And why do you think I'm here? I dont know how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

I know this question it's three year old but maybe we can help someone, found this explained:

[directDebitTransaction aggregation in SEPA SDD XML Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897602/directdebittransaction-aggregation-in-sepa-sdd-xml-generator?rq=1)

```
$paymentInfo = SEPA\Factory\XMLGeneratorFactory::createXMLPaymentInfo();

$transactions = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$a = 0;
//add payment info transactions
foreach($transactions as $t)
{
    $paymentInfo->addDirectDebitTransaction(
        SEPA\Factory\XmlGeneratorFactory::createXMLDirectDebitTransaction()
            ->setInstructionIdentification(++$a)
            ->setEndToEndIdentification(++$a)
            ->setInstructedAmount(100.5)
            ->setDebtorName('DVORAK')
            ->setDebitIBAN('FR14 2004 1010 0505 0001 3M02 606')
            ->setDebitBIC('AABAFI22')
            ->setMandateIdentification('SDD000000016PFX071'.$a)
            ->setDateOfSignature('2013-08-03')
            ->setDirectDebitInvoice(++$a));

}

//set The payment info
$paymentInfo->setPaymentInformationIdentification(6222)
    ->setSequenceType('RCUR')
    ->setCreditorAccountIBAN('MD24 AG00 0225 1000 1310 4168')
    ->setCreditorAccountBIC('AABAFI42')->setCreditorName('Amazing SRL')
    ->setCreditorSchemeIdentification('FR07ZZZ519993')
    ->setRequestedCollectionDate('2013-08-06');
```

//create SEPA file

\SEPA\Factory\XMLGeneratorFactory::createXmlGeneratorObject(\SEPA\XMLGenerator::PAIN_008_001_02)
      ->addXmlMessage(
      SEPA\Factory\XMLGeneratorFactory::createXMLMessage()->setMessageGroupHeader(

```
      SEPA\Factory\XMLGeneratorFactory::createXMLGroupHeader()
          ->setMessageIdentification($identificacionFichero = 1)
          ->setInitiatingPartyName($datos['nombreCliente'] = 'test')
          ->setPrivateIdentification($identificador=123)
  )->addMessagePaymentInfo($paymentInfo)

)->save($fileExist = realpath(__DIR__) . '/xml_files/sepa_demo.xml');
```